# Laravel 5.6 many to many with relation table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm stuck with my model relationship.

I have multiple table :

- table Lots
- table Etages
- table Options
- table Piece

I have a many to many relationship between Lots/Etages, Lots/Options.

I have one to many relationship between Options/Piece.

And I need a many to many relationship between Options / Lot and Options / Etage.

Options and piece data are fill after Etages data.

So my way to do handle this is :

- table Etage_Lot to handle many to many relationship between Lot and Etage.
- table Option with piece_id to handle one to many relationship between Option and Piece.
- table Lot_Option with Etage_lot_id and option_id.

Is it the right way to handle it ?

I create a EtageLot model with this :

```
public function lot(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\Lot');
}

public function etage(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\Etage');
}
```

My Lot model :

```
public function etages(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Copro\Etage');
}

public function etageLots(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Copro\EtageLot');
}
```

My Etage model :

```
public function lots()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Copro\Lot');
}
```

My Option model :

```
public function piece(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\Piece');
}

public function EtageLot(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\EtageLot','etage_lot_id');
}
```

And finally my piece model :

```
public function variantes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Copro\Variante');
}
```

Is it ok ? Especially for foreigner keys, I'm lost.

Thank for your help

Comment: are you get any solution,till now ???

Comment: No solution at the moment